# What is a good lightweight webradio program

Tags: windows, software-rec, streaming, media-player

I am currently using [Screamer Radio](http://www.screamer-radio.com/) but it is a little bit buggy. It freezes a lot if internet connection is bad and can not continue if there are interruptions in the internet connection.

I am not interested in some full sized MP3/media player, just a simple (with low memory footprint) application that can play streaming internet radio stations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using **[Spider Player](http://spider-player.com/)**. Yes, it's a fully fledged audio player (and the best one there is IMHO), but the footprint is hard to beat (7.5 MB disk space, less than 5 MB memory usage, portability). Spider Player has its own Radio Directory:

[image]

> Discover thousands of radio stations
>   around the globe with fast and easy
>   search in Shoutcast and Icecast radio
>   directories right within Spider
>   Player.

[image]

*Spider Player is freeware.*

(Pro version available with enhanced conversion utilities)

Answer (score 2):

I use [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/) for streaming radio and MP3s.  I love the hotkey support and the fact that you can hide it completely while it is running -- nothing in the task bar or in the system tray.

Memory-wise:

- ~8 MB installed
- 1 MB run-time
  memory usage
- ~7 MB VM usage (I have a pretty big playlist loaded most of the time)

Comment: AIMP is nice alternative to Winamp on Windows (and Audacious with a Winamp skin on Linux)

Answer (score 1):

I listen my favorite radio station right in the browser in Google Chrome with [Chrome-Radio](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hgjdhckebbdoobhniheihpdogeoeelbn). You can add station and create favorite list and lots more things. Try it! It is really cool.

Answer (score 0):

If your definition of application includes web apps (as opposed to just traditional desktop programs), check out [Slacker Radio](http://www.slacker.com/).  It provides bunch of preset stations with DJs, and allows you to create custom stations based on your favorite songs/bands.  Like Spider, the basic version is free but there are "premium" features available if you're willing to pay for them.  I've never had problems with it being buggy, but it does require JavaScript.

Other web app radio stations are [Pandora](http://www.pandora.com/) and [last.fm](http://www.last.fm/).  Slacker is my favorite of the three, but this is definitely a "your mileage may vary" situation.

Comment: "We are deeply, deeply sorry to say that due to licensing constraints, we can no longer allow access to Pandora for listeners located outside of the U.S. We will continue to work diligently to realize the vision of a truly global Pandora, but for the time being we are required to restrict its use. We are very sad to have to do this, but there is no other alternative." - from the Pandora site

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't tried it yet, I've heard "Last.fm" is good. Firefox even has an addon (fire.fm?) so you can run it through the browser.